# Data validation drop down list - not showing first value?

Tags: excel

I have very strange situation which I am not sure how to resolve.

I have list of values:

[image: Values]

But once people try to use the drop down list all they can see is this and they think there is no `Perm` option. Obviously all they need to do is to scroll up, but not everybody is smart enough to do so.

[image: Drop down list]

Is there any way to make the list bigger, or maybe set this up somehow so the `perm` will be visible from the start.

Comment: Just don't include a blank cell in your list source. The DV list will select a matching item if it can, so it's matching your blank cell with the blank at the end of the list.

Comment: You are right. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Excel will default to the first blank entry in the set when viewing the PickList. If you want a blank in the the PickList, make it the first element in the range. If you don't require a blank then you can simply edit your range to not include that last cell.

I've not found a way to enlarge the picklist window directly. But if you 'zoom in' on the page the picklist window will enlarge with the enlargement of the cells.